# Error in connecting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

My mysql password contains this symbol "]" and when I enter it here:

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DATABASE_localhost, DATABASE_main, DATABASE_my]password, DATABASE_gigi);
```

I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in /home2/gigi/public_html/includes/connection.php on line 18

what should I do?

Comment: You're missing the quotes in the strings

Comment: Please, what are you tring to do here ? What are theses DATABASE_localhost , ...?

Comment: Do you know what a parse error is? Code that cannot even run can't obviously connect to a database, or generate pictures, or anything at all.

Comment: **stop** suppressing errors with `@`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose your passed arguments in quotes. Try:

```
 $dbc = mysqli_connect('your_host', 'your_username', 'your_pass]word', 'your_database_name');
```